# VB Regex.Replace with repeating brackets

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I am trying to search in a string for a certain value and replace it with another value.

The example:

String: `"/accounts/{accountId}/cheques/{chequeId}/cancel"`

I am trying to replace anything between { and } with the number 1.

So I would end up with:

String: `"/accounts/1/cheques/1/cancel"`

I am using the following:

```
prepedURI = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(prepedURI, "{.*}", "1")
```

But unfortunately, the Replace function is returning:
String: "/accounts/1/cancel"

It seems to be ignoring the first } and replacing everything up to the 2nd }.

Any advice?

Excuse my dumb. This is my first Regex experience, and I am trying my best to understand all these 'flags' in the pattern.

Example (you can paste into a button click event to see what I mean):

```
Dim prepedURI As String = "/accounts/{accountId}/cheques/{chequeId}/cancel"
prepedURI = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(prepedURI, "{.*}", "1")
MsgBox(prepedURI)
```

Comment: `*` (and the other quantifiers) match as much as possible by default, and `.` includes `}`. You could exclude `}` with `[^}]` or be non-greedy with `.*?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ? before the closing curly brace

```
{.*?}
```

Working example can be found at the following link -
http://rubular.com/r/1LpnGNC3sC